# Inside of a "Make: New channel" action step, the Opacity reads "50". Why? (Photoshop CS5)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I made an action that create a new channel for masking purposes.

When I inspect the action, the "Make" command has an `Opacity:` property set to `50`.

Image:

[image]

I want to know why this happens and if it will affect anything. Everything seems to work fine, but this just leaves me scratching my head.

Comment: Obviously Chanel is very careful to design their masking creme to have at least some degree of transparency. If you asked for a new Avon (or some other inexpensive brand) the result would be rather different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spot channel or mask channel “transparency” is just a visualization property, determining how the channel is to be shown on screen, but not affecting the RGB values of your end result.

In later versions they renamed it to ‘solidity’ to avoid confusion with the other transparencies, eg. Layer transparency.